# Split string and take required value out TCL

Tags: tcl

I am trying to take certain value out from file name to use.
For example I have `7.32.56R_Znada.iso`

I am only interested in `Znada.iso` that means after _ (underscore)
Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to use `split` with `_` as the separator, and `lindex` to pick the piece you want.

```
set inputData "7.32.56R_Znada.iso"
set wantedValue [lindex [split $inputData "_"] end]
```

Or you could use regular expression matching.

```
regexp {.*_(.+)} $inputData -> wantedValue
```

Answer (score 2):

if

```
  set inputData "7.32.56R_Znada.iso"
```

Then try:

```
  set wantedValue [string range $inputData [expr [string last "_" $inputData]+1] end]
```

or without the filename extension use:

```
set wantedValue [string range $inputData [expr [string last "_" $inputData]+1] [expr [string last "." $inputData]-1]]
```

Comment: `string range $inputData [string last "_" $inputData]+1 end` also works in 8.6, and use `file rootname` to strip extensions.